# Improving (shortening) my list comprehension with lambda x function?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, list-comprehension

**!!! I know I could use Counter() here, but that's not the point !!!**

Giving the code below:

```
test =[['a',1],['a',2],['b',3], ['c',5],['a',7],['c',9]]

{i:[test[x][0] for x in range(len(test))].count(i) for i in [test[x][0] for x in range(len(test))]}

output: {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

Is there a way to avoid repeating the sequence without creating another variable:

```
[test[x][0] for x in range(len(test))]
```

Comment: I absolutely forgot that `assignment expression cannot be used in a comprehension iterable expression` [(PEP 572)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/). So I do not see another solution than assigning the list to a variable.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? counting the first occurrence in the first elements of the tuples?

Comment: @Vovin Understood. Thank you anyway :)
@ Sheldonzy, Yes (nested lists not tuples ;)), look at my output which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from itertools import groupby

test =[['a',1],['a',2],['b',3], ['c',5],['a',7],['c',9]]

{key: sum(j[1] for j in i) for key, i in groupby(test, key=lambda x: x[0])}
```